# BFS through matrix maze stuck in loop

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, breadth-first-search

This code finds a path through a binary matrix to a location with '9'.

Each iteration, dequeues a root and checks if all children are in bound and contain  '0'. If so, that child is added to the queue.

Each que element 'Box' has a parent, which will give the path if followed once the target is reached.

The code gets stuck because the que somehow just increases in size and is never empty. Am I missing something?

```
public static Queue<Box> q = new LinkedList<Box>();
    public static void searchPath(int[][] maze, int x, int y, ArrayList<Integer> path) {
        q.add(new Box(x,y,null));

        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            Box p = q.poll();

            if (maze[p.y][p.x] == 9) {
                System.out.println("Exit is reached!");
                getPath(p, maze, path);
                return;
            }

            if(isFree(maze, p.x+1,p.y)) {             
                Box nextP= new Box(p.x+1,p.y,p);
                q.add(nextP);
            }

            if(isFree(maze, p.x-1,p.y)) {               
                Box nextP= new Box(p.x-1,p.y,p);
                q.add(nextP);
            }

            if(isFree(maze, p.x,p.y+1)) {               
                Box nextP= new Box(p.x,p.y+1,p);
                q.add(nextP);
            }

            if(isFree(maze, p.x,p.y-1)) {
                Box nextP= new Box(p.x,p.y-1,p);
                q.add(nextP);
            }
        }
    }


    public static boolean isFree(int[][] maze, int x, int y) {
        if((x >= 0 && x < maze.length) && (y >= 0 && y < maze[x].length) && (maze[y][x] == 2 || maze[y][x] == 0 || maze[y][x] == 9)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        
            
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getPath(Box node, int[][] maze, ArrayList<Integer> path){
        while(node!=null){
            path.add(node.x);
            path.add(node.y);
            maze[node.y][node.x] = 2;
            node = node.parent;
        }
        return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to keep a track of the visited nodes.

`0,0` will queue `0,1`, `0,1` will queue `0,0` again, and this will go on indefinitely. As soon as you pop the queue, mark the node as visited. While queueing neighbours for a root, don't enqueue the visited ones.

Comment: Using a new field called 'visited' and only enqueueing when false, I get a correct path but only down / right moves. so if the map requires up or left turns, i get back into the loop.

Comment: @beatmaister why would the path require you to get back in the loop?

Comment: For some reason the build-in visited field just worked out that way, but I just tried the same thing using a HashMap<> to store coordinate strings which is O(1) lookup anyway, so now it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @beatmaister a "built-in" visited field might not have been working since you're creating a new `Box` node each time (which could have led to an incorrect implementation). Since this answer solves your issue, consider marking it as accepted.